# Integrate does not converge while Fourier transform does

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, fourier-analysis, convergence

Let us say I want Mathematica to compute the integral

$$\int dx \, \text{sign} (x) \, \frac{1}{1+x^2} = 0 \, .$$

Indeed

```
Integrate[Sign[x] 1/(1+x^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

gives the answer `0`. I am however interested in computing the integral in the Fourier space, i.e. in the (equivalent) form

$$\int dt \, \mathcal{F} \big[ \text{sign} (x) \big] (t) \, \mathcal{F} \bigg[ \frac{1}{1+x^2} \bigg] (t) \, ,$$

where $\mathcal{F}[f(x)](t)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$. In our case this is

$$\int dt \, \frac{i}{t} \, e^{- |t|} \, .$$

But now

```
Integrate[Exp[-Abs[t]] I/t, {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

gives `Integrate::idiv: Integral of (I E^-Abs[t])/t does not converge on {-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}`. Why? Is there something I can tell `Integrate` to give me the right answer in this kind of situations?

Comment: @yarchik: Can you ground your claim giving us an accessible reference? TIA.

Comment: @yarchik: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) says "The Fourier transform translates between convolution and multiplication of functions. If f(x) and g(x) are integrable functions with Fourier transforms f̂(ξ) and ĝ(ξ) respectively, then the Fourier transform of the convolution is given by the product of the Fourier transforms f̂(ξ) and ĝ(ξ) (under other conventions for the definition of the Fourier transform a constant factor may appear).".

Comment: @yarchik: Sorry, don't understand you. Ungrounded statements do not make a good impression. Can you elaborate your previous comment, giving us a possible answer to the question? TIA.

Comment: @yarchik: Sorry, again ungrounded $$\int dx f(x) g(x) = \int dt \mathcal{F}[f](t)  \mathcal{F}[g](-t).$$ It should be noticed that `InverseFourierTransform[Convolve[Exp[-Abs[t]], I/t, t, y], y, t]` returns the input.

Comment: @yarchik: If I state a non-trivial claim, I try to give an accessible reference to it.

Comment: Not clear what is expected to happen, but note that FT of product is not going to be product of FTs.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote "Why? Is there something I can tell Integrate to give me the right answer in this kind of situations?". Mathematica is right: the improper integral `Integrate[Exp[-Abs[t]] I/t, {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]` diverges because of the singularity at the origin. One can calculate its principal value by

```
Limit[Integrate[Exp[-RealAbs[t]] I/t, {t, -Infinity, -\[Epsilon]}, 
Assumptions -> \[Epsilon] > 0] +   Integrate[Exp[-RealAbs[t]] I/t, {t, \[Epsilon], Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> \[Epsilon] > 0], \[Epsilon] -> 0]
```

> `0`

It should be noticed that

```
Integrate[Exp[-RealAbs[t]] I/t, {t, -Infinity, 0, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

returns the input.

Comment: And why adding `PrincipalValue -> True` does not return `0`?

Comment: @MBolin: Don't know it.