# FourierCosCoefficient for function with singularity

Tags: symbolic, fourier-analysis, singularity

`FourierCosCoefficient` is way more powerful than I expected. For example,

```mathematica
In[1] := Table[FourierCosCoefficient[1/(2 - 2 Cos[x]), x, i], {i, -5, 5, 1}]
Out[1] = {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5}
```

```
In[2] := FourierCosCoefficient[1/(4 - 2 Cos[x] - 2 Cos[y]), {x, y}, {2, 3}]
Out[2] = -((8/3 + \[Pi] - Log[2])/\[Pi])
```

These are indeed the correct results.
However, the functions above have singularities, so we can't obtain the results by just integration.
How does `FourierCosCoefficient` find the results? What algorithm does `FourierCosCoefficient` take for the above examples?

Comment: I remembered now from class, that at point of discontinuity of the function, the series converges to the average of the function at that point.  But not sure this helps with your function, since at zero it blows up. But see [Fouriercoscoefficient-for-generalized-function-with-singularity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/299851/fouriercoscoefficient-for-generalized-function-with-singularity) for related discuassion

Comment: I'm currently teaching EE261, *The Fourier transform and its applications* at Stanford (using *Mathematica*) and can confirm that such series converge to the average of limits on either side of a discontinuity.  The square wave function is the clearest case.

Comment: @Nasser Hi, the "Fourier series coefficient" of $f(x)=(2-2\cos{x})^{-1}$ is $\tilde{f}_n = -|n|/2$. This is not a conventional Fourier series because $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |n|\exp{\mathrm{i}nx}$ is nowhere convergent. The proper way is to understand it as the Fourier transformation between a distribution on $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ and a distribution on $\mathbb{Z}$. I'm surprised that Mathematica can give results in this vastly generalized sense.

Comment: @Nasser: The link refers to this actual page. What was your intention?

Comment: @Leo: Fourier series are meant for functions without a pole. So I am not sure that in such a case the result is always correct and coincides with some extensions/generalizations of Fourier series.

Comment: Opps, no I pasted wrong link. Here it is again [integrate-does-not-converge-while-fourier-transform-does](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264133/integrate-does-not-converge-while-fourier-transform-does)  there few more like this as well.

Comment: The function  defined by `1/(2 - 2  Cos[x])` is a usual function, not a generalised function. Its Fourier series does not exist since the function is not integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Just to compare, the code of Maple `with(OrthogonalExpansions):FourierSeries(1/(2-2*cos(x)), x = -Pi .. Pi, n, 'Coefficients');` results in $${\frac {\infty }{\pi}}+\sum _{i=1}^{n} \left( {\frac {\cos \left( ix
 \right) }{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\!{\frac {\cos \left( ix \right) }{2-2
\,\cos \left( x \right) }}\,{\rm d}x} \right) 
 $$ and , for example, `int(cos(3*x)/(2-2*cos(x)), x = -Pi .. Pi);` performs $\infty$.

Comment: [CASE:5119482] has been submitted by me.

Comment: Concerning you second example, `Integrate[
 1/(4 - 2  Cos[x] - 2  Cos[y])*Cos[2 x]*Cos[3 y], {x, -Pi, 
  Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]` crashes my comp.

Comment: @user64494: Can you stop editing OP question if you do not understand the topic? Leave the title as it was typed by OP.

Comment: @azerbajdzan: Please indicate the distribution (generalized function) in the question.

Comment: @Leo: Concerning your comment, `Sum[RealAbs[n]*Exp[I*n*x], {n, -k, k}]` results in `(1/((-1 + E^(
  I x))^2))E^(-I k x) (-E^(I x) + E^(I (1 + k) x) + E^(I x + I k x) - 
   E^(I k x + I (1 + k) x) + k - E^(I x) k - 
   E^(I k x + I (1 + k) x) k + E^(I k x + I (2 + k) x) k)` Both `Limit` and `DiscreteLimit` of it as `k->Infinity` return the inputs. Substitution `{k -> 100, x -> 1.}`  results in `-6.75723 + 1.64313*10^-14 I`, substitution `{k -> 1000, x -> 1.` produces `2075.02 + 0. I`.

Comment: `Table[FourierSinCoefficient[1/(2 - 2  Sin[x]), x, i], {i, -5, 5, 1}]` returns `{5 + 46/(3 \[Pi]), 0, -3 - 10/\[Pi], 0, (
 2 + \[Pi])/\[Pi], 0, -((2 + \[Pi])/\[Pi]), 0, 
 3 + 10/\[Pi], 0, -5 - 46/(3 \[Pi])}` though the function is not odd.

Answer (score 1):

I think `FourierCosCoefficient` is simply ignoring pole of the function at `x=0`. We can see it by computing indefinite integral and then substituting upper and lower bounds of integration - we get the same result as `FourierCosCoefficient`.

I am not sure whether it is a feature or simply a bug.

```
Table[1/π Integrate[1/(2 - 2 Cos[x]) Cos[k x], x], {k, -5, 5}];
(# /. x -> π) - (# /. x -> -π) & /@ %
```

---

```
{-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5}
```

Comment: Would this not be wrong math if this is what Mathematica did? Since Fundamental Theorem of Calculus which you used can't be applied if the integrand is not Continuous between the limits of integration?  Can FTC really be used if there are countable number of poles between the limits? I did not think so.

Comment: This is definitely a bug in `FourierCoefficient`: `Integrate[1/(2 - 2  Cos[x])*Cos[3*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]` performs "Integrate::idiv: Integral of Cos[3 x]/(2-2 Cos[x]) does not converge on {-\[Pi],\[Pi]}.".

Comment: [CASE:5119482] has been submitted by me.

Comment: @Nasser: As OP said in his comments it can have some sense not as a function but as a distribution.

Comment: @azerbajdzan: Are you serious? Can you indicate this distribution (generalized function)?

Comment: @user64494: Have you read OP comment under the question? His explanation is more concrete.

Comment: @three777:   Can you indicate this distribution (generalized function)?  OP does not do it.

Comment: @azerbajdzan: There is no distribution (generalized function) in the question. There are functions with singularities which have no Fourier series in the question.